# Displaying posts made by user that is logged in - c#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have converted the session into a string in the .cs file,

```
      String username = Session["SELLER"].ToString();
```

This is my code for the .aspx file.

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ViewAdvertisement" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ElmtreeConnection  %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT Products.Name, Products.Price, Products.Description, Products.DatePosted, Products.CategoryId, Products.Image, Products.Username

        FROM Products

        WHERE Products.Username = @username">

          <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="username" QueryStringField="Username" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So how do I display the posts of the user logged in, as clearly my code isn't right at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing the current user name in session (That's the SELLER variable purpose?), if that understanding is correct, use the asp:SessionParameter:

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="username" SessionField="SELLER" Type="String" />
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks so much, this worked perfectly.